# Type text, then rotate and scale with JQUERY -- How?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a project coming up that is going to require that my users be able to enter a text string into a text input and then be able to rotate and scale the text over a background image. Once they position their text over the background image, I need to be able to somehow feed the final image to the shopping cart and eventually to the backend so the producer of these custom products can see visually what the client wanted in terms of text placement.

People have suggested the HTML5 canvas element, but I need browser support back to IE7 or 8 at least.

Fabric.JS looks promising but i don't know.

Any suggestions. I'm wanting to do this with php (codeigniter) and JQUERY?

Comment: PHP and CI are on the back end and have nothing to really do with where the magic happens - in the front end: HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: Fabric.js **requires** canvas.